# Socket.io : How do I handle all incoming messages on the server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to be able to handle all messages that are coming in from clients in a single handler.

Example client code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'test' });
socket.emit('chat', { hello: 'test' });
```

Example server code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}); });
```

I'd like to be able to log every message even if its sent on news, chat or whatever other name using emit. Is this possible?

Note: The above server code does not work. There is nothing currently logged. I am just wondering if there is a single event which could be handled for all messages for every emit name.

Comment: Maybe this => http://stackoverflow.com/a/7491506/11926?

Comment: See here for a solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9674248/362536

Answer (score 5):

That is possible by overriding **socket.$emit** function

```
//Original func
var x = socket.$emit;

socket.$emit = function(){
     var event = arguments[0];
     var feed  = arguments[1];

     //Log
     console.log(event + ":" + feed);

    //To pass listener  
    x.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));       
};
```

Comment: Does this work on incoming messages, because from the function name it suggests it is a function for outgoing messages?

Answer (score 2):

It's even easier on Socket.Io >3 using the [`socket.onAny(listener)`](https://socket.io/docs/v3/listening-to-events/#socket-onAny-listener):

```js
this.socket.onAny(m => {
    ..
});
```

---

This is supported out of the box now as of Socket-io 2.0.4, you simply need to register a middle ware (source from [socketio-wildcard](https://github.com/hden/socketio-wildcard)):

> As of Socket.io v2.0.4 (commit), you can use a socket middleware to
> catch every incoming Packet, which satisfies most of
> socketio-wildcard's use cases.
>
> ```js
> io.on('connection', (socket) => {
>   socket.use((packet, next) => {
>    // Handler
>    next();
>  });
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/434) with Socket.IO.

At this time, if you really need it, you will probably have to fork Socket.IO. See [3rd-Edens comment](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/434#issuecomment-2338366) for how to do it.

Comment: Well, this definitely isn't the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: Me neither, but that's the current situation. On the other hand, the changes from 3rd-Edens comment are only 3-5 lines and should be easy enough to implement.