# passing callback function in overriding socket.io on() nodejs

Tags: node.js

I referred [Socket.io : How do I handle all incoming messages on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001143/socket-io-how-do-i-handle-all-incoming-messages-on-the-server?answertab=active#tab-top)
answered by Ganesh Kumar to override the on() but i am unable to pass a callback function as argument. Why is it so? Can't i pass callback function in this?

My code snippet is like:

```
socket.$emit = function(callback)
{
   ....
   callback()
}
```

It is flagging error and treating callback as string. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the regular emit function you cannot pass a callback.

In the overridden version you can only accept the same arguments as the regular version.

Comment: so is there no way i can use my callback? Its a must for my app.

Comment: Can somebody suggest some alternatives?